# Importing CSV file from data import wizard in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, import

I've to import some data from a CSV file formatted with *Excel* and in UTF-8 encoding.

The error thrown at me when importing the data refers to fields with blank spaces that should be set to `null`:

> incorrect integer value '' for column 'name_column' at row 1

I tried to change the format coding to set `null`/`NULL`/`none` instead of blank spaces in the *Excel* fields, but the result is the same.

I cannot import the data by query because `LOAD DATA` is not supported by my MySQL version.

Comment: Maybe shows us a few rows which are having problems.

Comment: Is this even about programming or just a problem with using an Excel import function?